# How did an uninvolved user delete my answer?

Tags: discussion, bug, deleted-answers

[image: Screenshot of the deleted answer, a list of some free chess engines.]

[My +3 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4813568) was apparently deleted by an uninvolved user without a proper user name, acting alone skipping voting. Is this a bug?

Comment: Do you have a link to the question, so that 10k+ users can have a look at your answer?

Comment: @ivarni No reasonable user would choose such a name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658743/best-chess-engine-under-permissive-free-software-license/4813568#4813568

Comment: @SmallChess "No reasonable user would choose such a name" -- Not really; there are plenty of proper contributors using such user names.

Comment: The question altogether was deleted

Comment: @Vega Then who is that user?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1867/do-closed-questions-ever-get-deleted

Comment: The attribution to user319181 does look like a bug. The [post history for your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4813568/revisions) claims it was deleted and then undeleted by this user back in 2011, as if you had posted it using an account which has been deleted since then, with the post having been migrated to your account (I don't know if that was actually the case).

Comment: I would remove the _"spammer"_ allegations from the question. They seem rather inaccurate and based on false premises.

Comment: I agree with @yivi unless you want people writing answers as to why the user isn't a spammer.  If that is the answer you want then no need to edit, but I assume your want a different answer, so calling someone a spammer who (probably isn't) is going to be a distraction

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the post timeline? And of the question's probably. Your answer just got deleted because the question it was attached to was of low quality, and was deleted. But it seems unlikely a single regular user could be responsible for that.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I have edited it myself. This might well be a report of an actual bug; it is no use for anyone to focus on that distraction.

Comment: User319181 was in fact you.  Still visible in this [way-back machine snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20100420232025/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658276/how-to-use-linq-to-entities-for-filtering-when-many-methods-are-not-supported) of your first question, associated back then with the "Kinderchocolate" account name.  Perhaps you can remember the account merge, might have happened as long as 8 years ago.

Comment: @HansPassant My post was deleted 3 hours ago. I have this user name (SmallChess) for a long time. It was not me.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah, the spammer has been found! I guess it’s true what they say about “assume”.

Comment: @DanBron No it's a bug or a hack. Not me.

Comment: The answer WAS DELETED by a few hours

Comment: When a question gets deleted, the same timing is reported to the answers which are marked as deleted too. It's the case for that question. All the answers are deleted 4hours ago as the Q

Comment: Your answer wasn't deleted. The whole question was deleted.

Comment: @SmallChess it was indeed you. The bug is in the attribution of the most recent deletion, is all.

Comment: So the bug is that the deletion is attributed to an old name of the poster instead of the question’s OP, probably because the post already had a deletion and undeletion entry from the (old name of the) poster in its history.

Comment: @poke that is the correct analysis with as only remark that it is not a bug but [tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: @rene Is it "by design" in the sense that it was deemed a corner case too unimportant to bother with?

Answer (score 6):

The timeline of relevant events is:

- Jan 27 '11 at 06:55: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4813568/2751851) posted by SmallChess (you).
- Aug 11 '11 at 03:16: Answer deleted by user319181, which no longer exists. [The timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4813568/timeline) shows no other delete votes or review events.
- Aug 11 '11 at 03:19: Answer undeleted by user319181.
- Aug 11 '11 at 03:20: Answer edited by SmallChess.
- Jun 12 '15 at 00:53: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2658743/2751851) closed as off-topic/recommendation. ([Timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2658743/timeline))
- Oct 07 '18 at 08:30: Question deleted, with votes by techraf, Dalija Prasnikar and pnuts.

Since only the OP (and mods, but there is no reason to suspect mod involvement here) can delete or undelete a post singlehandedly, and the timing of the 2011 events is consistent with a temporary deletion while a major edit is in course, the most plausible explanation is that user319181 was merged with your account at some point in the past -- and [Brad Larson tells us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375043/how-did-an-uninvolved-user-delete-my-answer/375086?noredirect=1#comment636541_375086) that is indeed the case:

> Yes, I checked the records and user319181 was indeed merged into the main account in 2013, after the deletion / undeletion occurred.

That being so, there appear to be two issues affecting the attribution of deletion events:

- The 2011 answer deletion causes the 2018 by-effect answer deletion to be wrongly attributed to user319181 (compare with [the other answers to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9446448/2751851), whose deletions have no attribution).
- The account merger didn't transfer attribution of the 2011 deletion and undeletion to your current account.

Comment: Yes, I checked the records and user319181 was indeed merged into the main account in 2013, after the deletion / undeletion occurred. The history didn't get rewritten at that point to indicate the new user, so it left the old username. This is a bit of an edge case, and I think I've only seen this one or two other times in my years here.

Answer (score -15):

The whole question is now deleted, and if a question is deleted, also its answers are deleted.

A possible explanation had been, that the original question was deleted by its OP. However, ordinary users can't delete their own questions, if any of its answers has at least 1 upvotes. And your answer had at least 3.

Your answer could have been deleted by community votes, however answers with positive votes can't be deleted by community votes.

Also the question could have been deleted by community votes, but it couldn't happen by the vote of a single user, it requires at least 3 votes (of users with at least 10k). Furthermore, your deleted answers doesn't look on this way.

I can't see an explanation to your problem, it shouldn't happen. Hopefully someone will expain it in another answer.

Can you post - at least the deletion explanation part - of the question? It is important, what is there. Who deleted the question, and who posted id?